# Where can I find access to information provided by CNSA and Chinese scientists and reputable science authors?

Tags: china, space-agencies

The lack of finality to the current answer to [Was Queqiao in a halo or Lissajous orbit? Why do sources disagree?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45920/12102) is due in part to the difficulty of finding good, clear, reliable scientific sources that discuss [CNSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_National_Space_Administration) (China National Space Administration) deep space missions *in English*.

So I've asked this to see if sources can be identified. They could be twitter feeds, blogs, news sites or even CNSA websites or something else. They just need to be somewhat authoritative and scientific, rather than purely "popular" in nature.

Having substantial personal experience, I can say that google translate from Chinese to English, especially when a mixture of vernacular and technical terms are present, is frustrating and at times hilarious due in part to the very different natures of the two languages and the dearth of dual-language material that Google translate learns from.

Here are other questions that could potentially benefit.

- [What was Chang'e-2's 3D orbit in space? (since it's not in Horizons)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18851/12102)
- [Chang'e 4, what is planned during December 12 and January 3?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32952/12102)
- [Was Queqiao in a halo or Lissajous orbit? Why do sources disagree?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45920/12102) (also mentioned above)

These are examples I'm currently aware of, if you know of others that fit, please feel free to add.

Comment: I'll step up once I'm at HSK6 ;-)

Comment: @Ludo wow kudos to you! I can't tell if you're just speaking figuratively, or if you're seriously on your way.

Comment: I’m at level 3, but it’s an exponential scale... got some years to go still.

Comment: @DrSheldon hmm... it's been so long I can't remember what I'd meant (humor) In the future please feel free to just go ahead and fix errors like that; after all it's correct in the previous sentence and the second flows from the first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: This [Chinese Journal of Space Science](http://www.cjss.ac.cn/EN/0254-6124/home.shtml) has journal articles in English and it has a lot of technical info and it's incredibly good kuish. Thank you [@LarryTeds](https://twitter.com/larryteds). [Woo.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GwjfUFyY6M) (side note: with this under the belt, there are probably other journals like this, so search something like Chinese Journal of Space Technology might get you a hit.)

Aside from that honestly there is a lack of technical information in English on Chinese spaceflight. Occasionally there are [conference papers](https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2020/pdf/1459.pdf) which can cover a lot of good info in English, but they are relatively rare and not helped by stuff like [this](https://phys.org/news/2013-10-nasa-reverses-chinese-scientists.html). There is a significant amount of good analysis done on Chinese spaceflight, most notably by the US [military](https://www.uscc.gov/sites/default/files/Research/China%20Dream%20Space%20Dream_Report.pdf) however generally this is lacking in technical info.

In regards to twitter, I generally use this [search](https://twitter.com/search?q=(from%3AKaynouky%20OR%20from%3ACosmic_Penguin%20OR%20from%3ALarryTeds%20OR%20from%3Astarmil_admin%20OR%20from%3ALiuyiYiliu%20OR%20from%3ATheElegant055%20OR%20from%3Ahaibaraemily1%20OR%20from%3AAJ_FI)&src=typed_query) as a baseline search for Chinese spaceflight stuff.

I know that you're asking for English sources, but because most of the good info on Chinese spaceflight is on Chinese website and is where I source most of my info from. Chinese spaceflight journals in my experience provide useful information, though website functionality can sometimes be lacking. (note; there is a generally an English translated abstract to help as well and I mean the abstract is really the only important part of any paper anyway)

- [Journal](http://jdse.bit.edu.cn/sktcxb/indexen.htm) of Deep Space Exploration
- [Journal](http://www.yhxb.org.cn/EN/1000-1328/home.shtml) of Astronautics
- [Journal](http://www.zghtqk.com/SKY/journal/printDetail.html?qkid=41) of Aerospace Technology
- [Journal](https://mall.cnki.net/magazine/magadetail/ZRHT201902.htm) of Manned Spaceflight (paywalled)

For reference, in regards to Queqiao orbit, the Journal of Deep Space Exploration has a couple of papers on it, for example: this [paper](http://jdse.bit.edu.cn/sktcxb/en/article/doi/10.15982/j.issn.2095-7777.2019.03.008).

Forums are temperamental and a trek to navigate, but can be good source of info and graphics and [NSF](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?board=40.0) forums and [Spaceflightfans](http://bbs.spaceflightfans.cn/forum.php?mod=forumdisplay&fid=2) forums are my go to ones. This Chinese military [forum](https://lt.cjdby.net/forum-11-1.html) has a lot of good info, but requires an account to get access to media in posts and hyperlink technology, which in turn requires a Chinese phone number, which is difficult to source. (I tried using online Chinese phone numbers to no avail) This [forum](https://9ifly.spacety.com/forum-50-1.html) has a lot of technical information and papers, but it's a bit weird to use and I think it has an economy.

Also can we quickly take a moment to remember GBTimes. Some of Andrew Jones better articles were located in that beautiful website. (you can still access it with wayback machine, so if you find a GBTimes article you want to read use that). In general, Andrew Jones is my go to China spaceflight news person. He posts articles on most of the major space news websites.

In regards to Chinese news sites, [Xinhua](http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/list/scitech-space.htm) post news on Chinese spaceflight events in English. The [Weibo](https://weibo.com/u/1822161445?is_all=1) for the Chinese Lunar Exploration program covers most deep space news.
I also rate [Spaceflightfans](http://www.spaceflightfans.cn/).
There are several others; generally a google search for key terms is better than individual sites, especially for the most individual blog type posts like [this](https://new.qq.com/omn/author/6139469)

Empty forks builds good rockets.

Comment: I enjoyed being transported back to circa 1979/1980 pop music and spent some time [listening to and watching](https://youtu.be/qchPLaiKocI) Kool & the Gang and others ([1](https://youtu.be/WGU_4-5RaxU), [2](https://youtu.be/bbr60I0u2Ng)), returned here and realized that (at)LarryTeds was a Twitter handle rather than a Stack Exchange user name, but I'm curious how that Twitter account should be thanked for English articles appearing in the Chinese Journal of Space Science. Is it possible to elaborate? *Thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh A tweet of his pointed me in the direction of the journal. Of course it was also posted on NSF which I discovered later, but I give him credit now.

https://twitter.com/LarryTeds/status/1331804663486717953?s=20